# Como colocar itens de um Listview em strings.xml

Tags: android

tenho um listview personalizado, com imagens e texto:

```
private void createListView() {
    //Criamos nossa lista que preenchera o ListView
    itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();
    ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Alimentacao", R.drawable.alimentacao);
    ItemListView item2 = new ItemListView("Esporte", R.drawable.esporte);
    ItemListView item3 = new ItemListView("Saude", R.drawable.saude);


    itens.add(item1);
    itens.add(item2);
    itens.add(item3);


    //Cria o adapter
    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    //Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    //Cor quando a lista Ã© selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

São muitos itens.
A melhor forma para trabalhar seria passando para o string.xml os item ? como chamar os item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exatamente, a melhor forma é usar o `string-array` dentro do `strings.xml`.

Você teria um elemento, dentro do `strings.xml`, com a declaração do seu array:

```
<string-array name="categorias">
    <item>Alimentacao</item>
    <item>Esporte</item>
    <!-- Demais String's -->
</string>
```

Para usar basta usar o método `getStringArray` da `Resources`.

Por exemplo:

```
String[] categorias = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categorias);
```

---

No caso dos `Drawable's`, você pode criar um outro array dentro do mesmo arquivo apenas armazenando o sufixo:

```
<string-array name="categorias_drawable">
    <item>alimentacao</item>
    <item>esporte</item>
    <!-- Demais Drawables -->
</string>
```

E acessar usando o `getIdentifier` da classe `Resources` para recuperar o `id` do `Drawable`:

```
int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(nomeDoDrawable, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

O `idDrawable` vai conter o mesmo valor que `R.drawable.nomeDoDrawable`.

---

Para usar as duas soluções com a classe do modelo basta recuperar os dois array's e iterar sobre eles e criar os itens:

```
String[] categorias = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categorias);
String[] drawableCategorias = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categorias_drawable);

for(int i = 0; i < categorias.length; ++i) {
    itens.add(new ItemListView(categorias[i], getResources().getIdentifier(drawableCategorias[i], "drawable", this.getPackageName()));
}

// itens possui a lista as classes do modelo populada
// com os dados do strings.xml
```

Comment: Mas nao entendi como fica no meu projeto, q uso uma classe de modelo, que recebe o Item e Imagem, como ficaria no meu caso? ItemListView é a classe que criei, no caso nao usaria mais ela?

Comment: Deu certo mann!!, valeu